# How to get the first image URL from both arrays from my JSON file using Klaxon?

Tags: java, android, json, url, klaxon

My JSON

```
[
 
    "first_flight": "2010-12-08",
    "flickr_images": [
      "https://i.imgur.com/9fWdwNv.jpg",
      "https://live.staticflickr.com/8578/16655995541_7817565ea9_k.jpg",
      "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2815/32761844973_4b55b27d3c_b.jpg",
      "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8618/16649075267_d18cbb4342_b.jpg"
    ],
     "flickr_images": [
      "https://farm8.staticflickr.com/7647/16581815487_6d56cb32e1_b.jpg",
      "https://farm1.staticflickr.com/780/21119686299_c88f63e350_b.jpg",
      "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8588/16661791299_a236e2f5dc_b.jpg"
    ],
 ]
```

My code

```
val result = URL("https://api.spacexdata.com/v4/dragons").readText()
        val parser: Parser = Parser()
        val stringBuilder: StringBuilder = StringBuilder(result)
        jsonArray = parser.parse(stringBuilder) as JsonArray<JsonObject>
    ....
    **rocket.image = jsonArray.string("flickr_images")[i]?.get(0).toString() - doesnt work**
```

Have *java.lang.ClassCastException: com.beust.klaxon.JsonArray cannot be cast to java.lang.String*

Answer (score 0):

```
"flickr_images": [
  "https://i.imgur.com/9fWdwNv.jpg",
  "https://live.staticflickr.com/8578/16655995541_7817565ea9_k.jpg",
  "https://farm3.staticflickr.com/2815/32761844973_4b55b27d3c_b.jpg",
  "https://farm9.staticflickr.com/8618/16649075267_d18cbb4342_b.jpg"
]
```

first point is JsonObject is key-value pair .JsonArray is Collection of JsonObject .
so flickrimages is not a proper jsonArray Format.flickrimages is a List of String.so error comes.

and as per your Question you cannot get values from both flickrimages since this json has two keys with same name "flickrimages".so if you get value with key "flickrimages" by default only last added one value comes.

so its better to change the formatofjson that comes from url